# FlaskサーバのUnicodeDecodeErrorが出てしまう

Tags: python, flask, unicode

Flaskでサーバを起動してクライアントから画像データを受け取りし予測結果を返すプログラムなのですが実行するとサーバは起動するのですが以下のようなエラーが出て終了してしまいます。
機械学習を始めたばかりでわからない点が多いので、もしよろしければご教授お願いします。

構成：
Windous 10, Python 3.6.8, gevent 20.9.0, Flask 1.1.2

```
File "D:\zemi\re\keras-flask\train\myvenv\lib\site-packages\gevent\threadpool.py",
 142, in __run_task
    thread_result.set(func(*args, **kwargs))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x83 in position 0: invalid start byte
2024-01-16T09:51:50Z (<ThreadPoolWorker at 0x258207a12a8 thread_ident=0x3cb0 threadpool-hub=<Hub at 0x2581964df60
ad_ident=0x407c>>, <built-in function gethostbyaddr>) failed with
odeDecodeError

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 51, in <module>
    main(parser.parse_args())
  File "main.py", line 44, in main
    http_server.serve_forever()
  File "D:\zemi\re\keras-flask\train\myvenv\lib\site-packages\gevent\baseserver.py",
 398, in serve_forever
    self.start()
  File "D:\zemi\re\keras-flask\train\myvenv\lib\site-packages\gevent\baseserver.py",
 336, in start
    self.init_socket()
  File "D:\zemi\re\keras-flask\train\myvenv\lib\site-packages\gevent\pywsgi.py",
 1501, in init_socket
    self.update_environ()
  File "D:\zemi\re\keras-flask\train\myvenv\lib\site-packages\gevent\pywsgi.py",
 1513, in update_environ
    name = socket.getfqdn(address[0])
  File "D:\zemi\re\keras-flask\train\myvenv\lib\site-packages\gevent\_socketcommon.py",
 287, in getfqdn
    hostname, aliases, _ = gethostbyaddr(name)
  File "D:\zemi\re\keras-flask\train\myvenv\lib\site-packages\gevent\_socketcommon.py",
 259, in gethostbyaddr
    return get_hub().resolver.gethostbyaddr(ip_address)
  File "D:\zemi\re\keras-flask\train\myvenv\lib\site-packages\gevent\resolver\thread.py",
 66, in gethostbyaddr
    return self.pool.apply(_socket.gethostbyaddr, args, kwargs)
  File "D:\zemi\re\keras-flask\train\myvenv\lib\site-packages\gevent\pool.py",
 161, in apply
    return self.spawn(func, *args, **kwds).get()
  File "src\\gevent\\event.py", line 305, in gevent._gevent_cevent.AsyncResult.get
  File "src\\gevent\\event.py", line 335, in gevent._gevent_cevent.AsyncResult.get
  File "src\\gevent\\event.py", line 323, in gevent._gevent_cevent.AsyncResult.get
  File "src\\gevent\\event.py", line 303, in gevent._gevent_cevent.AsyncResult._raise_exception
  File "D:\zemi\re\keras-flask\train\myvenv\lib\site-packages\gevent\_compat.py",
 65, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "D:\zemi\re\keras-flask\train\myvenv\lib\site-packages\gevent\threadpool.py",
 142, in __run_task
    thread_result.set(func(*args, **kwargs))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x83 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

以下がmain.pyです。

```
import argparse
import keras

from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer
from cv2 import cv2
import numpy as np
from configparser import ConfigParser

def main(args):
    config = ConfigParser()
    config.read(args.config)
    model = keras.models.load_model(config['model'].get('model_path'))
    app = Flask(__name__)

    @app.route('/predict', methods=['POST'])
    def predict():
        img_file = request.files['file']
        img_bytes = img_file.read()
        image = np.asarray(bytearray(img_bytes), dtype=np.uint8)
        image = cv2.imdecode(image, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
        cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        image = image[np.newaxis,...]

        res = model.predict(image)
        out = res.argmax()
        prob = res[0, out]

        return jsonify({
            'status': 'OK',
            'class': int(out),
            'probability': float(prob)
        })


    host = config['server'].get('host')
    port = int(config['server'].get('port'))

    print('Starting server on host %s port %d' % (host, port))

    http_server = WSGIServer((host, port), app)
    http_server.serve_forever()        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    parser.add_argument('--config', default='settings.conf', type=str)

    main(parser.parse_args())
```

Comment: エラーメッセージ中の`<built-in function gethostbyaddr>) failed with UnicodeDecodeError`あたりから、こちらの記事と同様かもしれませんね。[FlaskでUnicodeDecodeErrorが出て接続できない](https://teratail.com/questions/329521) コンピューター名とかホスト名(FQDN?)を調べてみると良いかもしれません。

Comment: コンピューター名が日本語でした！！
すみませんありがとうございます！！

Comment: ひとつ前の質問もそうですが、もしコメント欄で解決した場合にはぜひご自身で「個別の回答」として投稿してもらうと、他のユーザーにも役立つと思います。